# Where is the latest source code of nvelocity

Tags: c#, nvelocity

I am thinking of using nvelocity as a template engine for some emails.
I am having problems of finding the latest source code of nvelocity. The GitHub source no longer exists.

The first version I get in google is on [codeplex](http://nvelocity.codeplex.com/) which I believe that is not the latest version of source code.

I pulled down the latest dll from [castleproject.org/castle/download.html](http://castleproject.org/castle/download.html) which states the latest date is 10 december 2010. Looking at [castleproject.org/git.html](http://castleproject.org/git.html) and clicking on the [nvelocity option](http://github.com/castleproject/NVelocity) I get a 404 error. Click on the castleproject github there is no reference to NVelocity.

Comment: First of, manners cost nothing. The first version I get in google is on codeplex which I believe that is not the latest version of source code.

Comment: Pardon if I sound rude in your opinion. Please elaborate which problems you have and what you have tried so far, so we do not make the same mistake as you and don't waste time on what you have tried already. Do not forget that we are not paid to help you, so please help _us_ to help _you_.

Comment: I pulled down the latest dll from http://www.castleproject.org/castle/download.html which states the latest date is 10 december 2010. Looking at http://www.castleproject.org/git.html and clicking on the nvelocity option I get a 404 error. Click on the castleproject github there is no reference to NVelocity.

Comment: Looking at their mailing list archives it sounds like they're in the middle of reorganising their github. You'd probably do best to ask on the [users list](http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-users) or [development list](http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-devel).

Comment: _"the latest date is 10 december 2010"_ ... so? Won't it run? Has it got known issues you will encounter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[NVelocity now lives in the MonoRail repository](https://github.com/castleproject/MonoRail/tree/master/MR2/NVelocity).